# Bokeh: Determine which model called an on_change event handler

Tags: python, bokeh

I have the following scenario where I want to execute a function with `on_change`:

```
def update_func:
    calling_widget = < I need the name of the widget here: "SelectorWidget" >
    do_something

SelectorWidget = MultiSelect(title="A widget", value = "default", options = option_list)

SelectorWidget.on_change('value', update_func)
```

The same `update_func` will be used on different widgets, and I'd like to be able to get the name of the Widget which triggered the function each time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
from functools import partial

# add a widget arg to standard callback signature
def update_func(attr, old, new, widget):
    # do something with widget

SelectorWidget = MultiSelect(title="A widget", 
                             value="default", 
                             options=option_list)

# use partial to make a callback callable with widget arg bound
SelectorWidget.on_change('value', 
                         partial(update_func, widget=SelectorWidget))
```